# Is there any way to hide vue props in page-source?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i'm using vue single component and passing props inside my blade fie...!
is there any way that i can hide props when viewing page-source ?

here is my output from page-source in chrome!

```
<my-component name="name" :brand="user_id&quot;:1,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null}" ></my-component>
```

i know that i can use spa but i want to know if there is any way that we hide theme when viewing page-source?!

Comment: you can encode this string smth like base64 or else and in the component decode it back. For example create prop :brandEncoded and in the component create computed property brand which will decode it back

Comment: if you are using webpack, then this will be minified if your concern is the name of the properties. Otherwise you can run a computed property and run encoding as mentioned above, but obviously the data will at some point in its transit be clear text if you are encoding it on the client side.